# How to make automatic scrolling up the table when showing the keyboard?

Tags: swift, uitableview

The first option (works)
If you use the UITableViewController class, then scrolling up works automatically.

Second option (not working)
But if you use UIViewController + UITableView, the table does not automatically scroll up.

Tell me please what can I do for the second option?

Resize tableView

```
func keyboardWillShow(_ notification: Notification) {
    //get the end position keyboard frame
    guard let keyInfo = notification.userInfo as NSDictionary? else {
        return
    }
    var keyboardFrame: CGRect = keyInfo.object(forKey: UIResponder.keyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey) as! CGRect
    //CGRect keyboardFrame = [[keyInfo objectForKey:@"UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey"] CGRectValue];
    //convert it to the same view coords as the tableView it might be occluding
    keyboardFrame = self.tableView.convert(keyboardFrame, from: nil)
    //calculate if the rects intersect
    let intersect: CGRect = keyboardFrame.intersection(self.tableView.bounds)
    if (intersect != CGRect.null) {
        //yes they do - adjust the insets on tableview to handle it
        //first get the duration of the keyboard appearance animation
        let duration: TimeInterval = keyInfo.object(forKey: UIResponder.keyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey) as! Double
        // adjust the animation curve - untested
        let curve: Int = (notification.userInfo![UIResponder.keyboardAnimationCurveUserInfoKey] as! Int) << 16
        //change the table insets to match - animated to the same duration of the keyboard appearance
        UIView.animate(withDuration: duration, delay: 0.2, options: UIView.AnimationOptions(rawValue: UInt(curve)), animations: {
            let height = intersect.size.height
            self.tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: height, right: 0)
            self.tableView.scrollIndicatorInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: height, right: 0)
        }, completion: nil)
    }
}
func keyboardWillHide(_ notification: Notification) {
    let keyInfo: NSDictionary = notification.userInfo! as NSDictionary
    let duration: TimeInterval = keyInfo.object(forKey: UIResponder.keyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey) as! Double
    let curve: Int = (notification.userInfo![UIResponder.keyboardAnimationCurveUserInfoKey] as! Int) << 16
    //change the table insets to match - animated to the same duration of the keyboard appearance
    UIView.animate(withDuration: duration, delay: 0.2, options: UIView.AnimationOptions(rawValue: UInt(curve)), animations: {
        self.tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets.zero
        self.tableView.scrollIndicatorInsets = UIEdgeInsets.zero
    }, completion: nil)
}
```

How to scroll to the desired cell? How to find the cell in which the cursor is now?

Wrote an additional function for the cell

```
class CustomTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {
    func scrollToCell() {
        if let tableView = self.getTableView() {
            if let index = tableView.indexPath(for: self) {
                UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.2, animations: {
                    tableView.scrollToRow(at: index, at: .none, animated: false)
                }, completion: nil)
            }
        }
    }
    private func getTableView() -> UITableView? {
        return (self.superview as? UITableView)
    }
}
```

I call this function on events:

```
UITextView::textViewDidBeginEditing
UITextField::textFieldDidBeginEditing
```

I think there is a better way

Comment: You can change the content inset of the table when keyboard notification is fired.

Comment: I found the event of showing and hiding the keyboard, but I do not know how to write the algorithm the same as in the UITableViewController

Comment: I found useful information - https://gist.github.com/TimMedcalf/9505416
But how to scroll through the reduced table if it is necessary to display the element in the visible zone?

Answer (score 0):

You can observe when the keyboard shows and then scroll the table to the top like this:

```
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector:
            #selector(keyboardWillShow(_:)), name:NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillShow, object: nil);
    }

    @objc
    func keyboardWillShow(_ notification: Notification) {
        let indexPath = IndexPath(row: 0, section: 0)
        self.tableView.scrollToRow(at: indexPath, at: .top, animated: true)
    }
```

Comment: We must not just scroll to the first cell. The task is to scroll if it is necessary to display the cell in which the text is being edited (UITextField border bottom)